# Vb.net - stream reader throws error when reading input stream of an http listener

Tags: vb.net, webserver

I have a strange error.

I do gat data over a webserver, respectively - I am running the webserver and I get data over post parameter from an external component.

The messages does contain images, which are base64 encoded.

Without Images, everything works as expected - however with images, in about 30% of all massages I do get an error.

[image]

It is the stream reader that causes the error. Basically it says invalid function.

This is the entire function:

```
Public Sub MyCollectFromTriggerInterface()


    Main.MessageObj.MyMessage("DLVPDataCollector: ", "Start thread for DLVP collection. (Trigger Interface)", 3)
    Main.LogObj.MsgLog("ClassDLVPDataCollector", "MyCollectFromTriggerInterface", "Start thread for DLVP collection. (Trigger Interface)")

    'Falls das Betriebssytem den Server nicht 
    If Not System.Net.HttpListener.IsSupported Then
        Main.MessageObj.MyMessage("DLVPDataCollector: ", "!!! Windows XP SP2, Server 2003, or higher is required to use the HttpListener class !!!", 3)
        Main.LogObj.ErrLog("ClassDLVPDataCollector", "MyCollectFromTriggerInterface", "Windows XP SP2, Server 2003, or higher is required to use the HttpListener class.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Den Listener starten.
    Dim listener As System.Net.HttpListener = New System.Net.HttpListener()
    Dim adr As String = Main.LoadSettingsObj.Settings_DlvpDatacollector_HTTPServerAddress_TriggerInterface
    listener.Prefixes.Add(adr)
    listener.Start()
    Main.MessageObj.MyMessage("DLVPDataCollector: ", "Listener started. (Trigger Interface)", 3)
    Main.LogObj.MsgLog("ClassDLVPDataCollector", "MyCollectFromTriggerInterface", "Listener started. (Trigger Interface)")

    While True

        'Wenn die Applikation beendet werden soll.
        If Main.EndApplication = True Then
            Main.MessageObj.MyMessage("DLVPDataCollector: ", "Stop thread for DLVP collection. (Trigger Interface)", 3)
            Main.LogObj.MsgLog("ClassDLVPDataCollector", "MyCollectFromTriggerInterface", "Stop thread for DLVP collection. (Trigger Interface)")
            Exit While
        End If

        'Auslesen, was der Client gesendet hat.
        Dim response As HttpListenerResponse = Nothing
        Dim context As HttpListenerContext = listener.GetContext()
        Dim PostParameter = New StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd()

        'Neuen Thread starten.
        Dim obj As New ArgumentsTo_MyDoWorkflowTI
        obj.Data = PostParameter
        Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf MyDoWorkflowTI)
        t.IsBackground = True
        t.Start(obj)

        'Antwort an den Client senden.
        Dim b As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ACK")
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200
        context.Response.KeepAlive = False
        context.Response.ContentLength64 = b.Length
        Dim output = context.Response.OutputStream
        output.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
        context.Response.Close()

    End While

End Sub
```

I guess it has something to do with the length of the message or some timeout issue or whatever...

Has anyone an idea?

The interface is getting data up to 4 times in a second.

Kr,

Andreas

This are the details of the exception:

[image]

Comment: If you click "View Detail..." in that exception message box then you will get more information about what went wrong.

Comment: Hi, I have just posted the details of the exception - however I still dont get it..

Comment: Does the external component report any error? Can you find the size of the message which causes the problem?